# What's the logic behind this program?

Tags: c, logical-operators

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  if(2&&3>1)
  printf("its greater");
  return 0;
}
```

How's this code showing 2&&3>1 as true?

Comment: 2 is true, 3>1 is true, true and(&&) true are true

Comment: Because of order of operations. `&&` is evaluated last. `3>1` is `true`, and `2` is boolean `true` too because any number different to `0` is.

Comment: Well, not `true` since we are talking C here, but you get the point.

Comment: Well, I got it, I missed the braces (2&&3)>1, anyways thanks.

Comment: @Havenard — not really "`&&` is evaluated last".  The LHS of the condition is evaluated (and there's a sequence point after it is evaluated).  If the LHS is false, the RHS is not evaluated; only if the the LHS is true is the RHS evaluated — and if the RHS is true, the overall expression is true, otherwise the overall expression is false.  Numerically, 0 is produced if the result is false, and 1 is produced if the result is true.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, yes, I'm just saying that like in math, there's an order of operations, it is not simply interpreted from left to right, as would be `(2&&3)>1`. In `2&&3>1` the operation `>` is processed before `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use if(x) with x is a value other than zero, it will be true! e.x: if(1), when(1), if(2), when(3>2)...
Therefore, (2) is true and (3>1) is true lead (2)&&(3>1) is true.